# Bijection between $\Delta(A)$ and $\mathrm{Max}(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras

> For a commutative Banach algebra, the mapping
>   $$\varphi \to \ker\varphi$$ is a bijection between $\Delta(A)$ and $\mathrm{Max}(A),$ where $\Delta(A)$ is the set of all multiplicative non-zero linear functionals on $A$ and  $\mathrm{Max}(A)$ is the set of all maximal modular ideals of $A.$

I've seen the proof of above given in *A Course in Commutative Banach Algebras* by *Kaniuth*. However, I was wondering if there is a way to prove injectivity without using the fact that $\ker \varphi$ has codimension $1$ in $A?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ker \varphi_1 = \ker \varphi_2=I,$ say.  Let $x \in A$. We need to show that $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x).$

**Case $1: \varphi_1(x)=0$.** Then we're done.

**Case $2: \varphi_1(x) \neq 0$.** Let $$y= \dfrac{x}{\varphi_1(x)}.$$
Then $\varphi_1(y)=1.$ Hence, $y$ is identity modulo $I$. Thus, $x-yx \in I=\ker \varphi_2.$ So, 
\begin{align*}
\varphi_2(x-yx)&=0\\
\varphi_2(x)&=\varphi_2(y)\varphi_2(x)\\
\varphi_2(y)&=1.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have $$\varphi_1(y)=\varphi_2(y).$$ From this it follows that  $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\ker \varphi_1=\ker\varphi_2\neq 0$, then $\varphi_1(1)=\varphi_2(1)=1$, hence  $x-\varphi_1(x)\in \ker\varphi_1=\ker\varphi_2.$ Therefore $\varphi_2(x-\varphi_1(x))=0 $, i.e. $\varphi_1(x)=\varphi_2(x)\forall x\in X$.

Comment: You're assuming that $A$ is unital.

Comment: Yes, but it is general. If $A$ is not unital, take $\tilde{A}$ as the unitization of $A$, and $\tilde{\varphi_1}(x,\lambda)=\varphi_1(x)+\lambda,$ $\tilde{\varphi_2}(x,\lambda)=\varphi_2(x)+\lambda$.